# How can I parse a string that contains wildcards and character classes in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, parsing

I would like to write a script that takes one argument that might look like this:

```
abc(ag)de*
```

`a`, `b`, `c` are literal characters.

`(ag)` means "an 'a' or a 'g'".

`*` means any one letter or number.

I want the script to create an Array of all the possible strings the input could represent. (The purpose is to check if they're available domain names.)

The input could also be something like `abc(ag)de(mnlop)` where there are more than on character class.

Seems like the first task is to split it into an Array or Arrays, so the first example would be...

```
[
  ['a'],
  ['b'],
  ['c'],
  ['a', 'g'],
  ['d'],
  ['e'],
  [
    'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g',
    # etc...
  ]
]
```

This is where I get stuck. I don't know how to split it up into pieces like that.

Any suggestions on how to approach it?

Comment: There is a word missing in the title between "a" and "that". I'm not sure what the correct word would be ("string"?), so you should fix that ;)

Comment: You may find the C# answer I posted at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710670/c-permutation-of-an-array-of-arraylists/710716#710716 helpful.  In your case, the arrays would be those you are generating already for your first stask.  The basic recursive algorithm should be relatively easy to translate to a solution for your problem.  But I don't know Ruby so I leave it to you or someone else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a pretty compact solution. It's in no way optimized for performance which puts some constraints on the patterns you supply e.g. too many wildcards is probably not the best idea.

Here's the code

```
input1 = "abc(ag)de*"
input2 = "abc(ag)de(mnlop)"

class Array
  def append_suffixes!(suffixes)
    self.replace suffixes.map { |a| self.map { |p| p + a }}.flatten
  end
end

def generate_combinations(pattern)
  combinations = [""]
  pattern.scan(/\(([^)]+)\)|(\*)|(\w+)/) do |group,wildcard,other|
    new_suffixes = case
      when group    : group.split('')
      when wildcard : [*'a'..'z']
      when other    : other
      else raise "Unknown match!"
    end
    combinations.append_suffixes! new_suffixes
  end
  combinations
end

p generate_combinations(input1)
p generate_combinations(input2)
p generate_combinations("**").size
```

The output from running the code above is (slightly edited):

```
["abcadea", "abcgdea", "abcadeb", "abcgdeb", "abcadec", 
 "abcgdec", "abcaded", "abcgded", "abcadee", "abcgdee", 
 "abcadef", "abcgdef", "abcadeg", "abcgdeg", "abcadeh", 
 "abcgdeh", "abcadei", "abcgdei", "abcadej", "abcgdej", 
 "abcadek", "abcgdek", "abcadel", "abcgdel", "abcadem", 
 "abcgdem", "abcaden", "abcgden", "abcadeo", "abcgdeo", 
 "abcadep", "abcgdep", "abcadeq", "abcgdeq", "abcader", 
 "abcgder", "abcades", "abcgdes", "abcadet", "abcgdet", 
 "abcadeu", "abcgdeu", "abcadev", "abcgdev", "abcadew", 
 "abcgdew", "abcadex", "abcgdex", "abcadey", "abcgdey", 
 "abcadez", "abcgdez"]

["abcadem", "abcgdem", "abcaden", "abcgden", "abcadel", 
 "abcgdel", "abcadeo", "abcgdeo", "abcadep", "abcgdep"]

676 # The number of two letter words i.e. 26*26
```

Please feel free to ask if you have any questions about the code above.

Answer (score 1):

If your * means only a single character, then I guess this is at least solvable. If it means "zero or more of any character", then it feels as if your solution space is bordering on the infinite, and thus will be kind of hard to return as an actual concrete value.

I think I would approach this by somehow splitting out the variable parts, figuring out how many variants each supports, then (conceptually) looping over all the variables in a nested way, forming one output string for each iteration of the innermost loop.

For the example string of "abc(ag)de*", this would boil down to this (Python-ish pseudo-code, my Ruby is not up for public use):

```
results = []
for x in "ag":
  for y in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":
    results.append("abc%sde%s" % (x, y))
```

The %s in the string on the final line is a format specifier, s simply means "string", and will cause the corresponding value from tuple to the right of the % operator after the string to be interpolated at that position.

Comment: The star means just one character.

Answer (score 1):

What you're essentially asking for is to take a regexp and generate all the strings it matches.

That was [Ruby Quiz #143](http://rubyquiz.com/quiz143.html). Have a look at the solutions on the left hand side.