# generate all combination

Tags: c#, algorithm, combinations

Given buckets of unique numbers, how do we generate all combinations where you choosing a number from each bucket only once.

For example, if given {1,12,3} and {4,22,6} the answer is:
1/4  12/22 3/6 
1/4  12/6  3/22 
1/22 12/4  3/6 
1/22 12/6  3/4 
1/6  12/4  3/22 
1/6  12/22 3/4

Of course, we don't just want 2 buckets, but n buckets.
And each bucket can contain any amount of numbers; the numbers are unique across buckets.

Any algorithm in c# would be appreciated.
I would expect the result to be something like: List<List<int[]>>

Thanks!

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far. People generally do not like to just write your code for you. As it is, this is a work description, not a question.

Comment: Smells like homework

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? If you have tried something and still not getting, then give us info on what you have tried so that we can guide you further to get it done.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generating all Possible Combinations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093622/generating-all-possible-combinations)

Comment: All the 'generating all possible combination' posts I have seen end up generating a cartesian product.  This is not quite that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

[C# Permutation of an array of arraylists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710670/c-permutation-of-an-array-of-arraylists)

And this:

[Fast permutation -> number -> permutation mapping algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506078/fast-permutation-number-permutation-mapping-algorithms)