# Array of array combinations 

Tags: c#, linq

How to generate various combinations of opposite values using LinQ/C#
I have a list of operators in an array like `"> < = + ="` i also have a function which can return me the opposite value of each item in an array.Opposite value of `">"` is `"<"` and so on.So considering the reverse operators for each and every value how to generate various possible combinations

Sample:
Problem Statement :

```
`string[] arrSample = new string[]{"!=","="};` //arrSample can be any object array with property values.The property can accept operator values like 
!=,=,>,< etc..
```

Expected Output:
The various combinations considering the reverse operator would be

```
Output Sequence1: =,!=
Output Sequence2: !=,=
Output Sequence3: = , =
Output Sequence4: !=,!=
```

Comment: Please can you supply the code for the reverse function - taa

Comment: @Jon Egerton: It doesnt have much of a code.Just returns the opposite value of any given operator.Say i pass "=" it returns me "!=" :-)

Comment: So do you just want to get a list of the passed operators and their reverse operator, and permute the lot? What would the output be for `string[] arrSample = new string[]{"!=","<","+"};`

Comment: I don't understand sequence3 and sequence4. How are the 2 operators different?

Comment: How is this reversing the operator, or am I missing something? You're just outputting each combination of the operators

Comment: @Jon Egerton the answer for your question is    [= > -]
[= < - ]
[= < +]
[!= > -]
[!= < -]
[!= > +]
[!= < -]
[!= < +]  totally 8 combinations for 3 operators

Comment: @Rob  If we just have = and = i.e = = So these operators will have to be reversed for combinations.Here the order doesnt matter. so for = and = The possible combinations will be =  != ; !=  = ; != != ; = =

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This turned out to be harder than it looks, but the following should demonstrate the idea.

There are two steps - create an array list pairs of each operator and its reverse and then recursively permute these together.

```
void DoProblem()
{
    //string[] arrSample = new string[] { "!=", "=" };
    string[] arrSample = new string[] { "!=", "<","+" };

    string[][] arrPairs = (from op in arrSample select new string[]{op, GetReverse(op)}).ToArray();

    List<Array> myList = new List<Array>();
    myList.AddRange(arrPairs);

    foreach (string x in Permute(0, myList))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }

}

List<string> Permute(int a, List<Array> x)
{
    List<string> retval = new List<string>();
    if (a == x.Count)
    {
        retval.Add("");
        return retval;
    }
    foreach (Object y in x[a])
    {
        foreach (string x2 in Permute(a + 1, x))
        {
            retval.Add(y.ToString() + "," + x2.ToString());
        }

    }
    return retval;
}


string GetReverse(string op)
{
    switch (op) {
        case "=":
            return "!=";
        case "!=":
            return "=";
        case "<":
            return ">";
        case "+":
            return "-";    
        default:
            return "";
    }
}
```

NOTE: The permute function is based on the permute an Array of Arrays answer here: [C# Permutation of an array of arraylists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710670/c-permutation-of-an-array-of-arraylists)

Comment: Whats the best way to thank someone?.Thank you so much.This saved my day (i should say lifetime).Thanks once again.

Comment: @SharpC - no problems - happy to help. It always nice when a bit of a brain teaser comes along.

Answer (score 0):

```
from operator in arrSample select operator + "," + ReverseOperator(operator)
```

Or did I miss something?

Comment: arrSample contains two operators.Implies the possible combinations would be 2*2 = 4. To give another example. If there are 5 operators then the total possible combinations would be 2*2*2*2*2 = 32. It's not just the opposite value but various possible combinations.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want a union?

```
    string[] arrSample = new string[]{"!=","="};

    var list = (
            from item in arrSample
            select item + "," + item
        ).Union(
            from revItem in arrSample
            select revItem + "," + ReverseOperator(revItem)
        );

    List<string> final = new List<string>(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find the following easiest way to two string arrays with different combination

string[] roles = { "abc", "e", "f", "h" };

string[] allRoles = { "a", "b", "c", "abc", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i" };

```
    foreach (string nextRole in allRoles)
    {
        if (Array.IndexOf(roles, nextRole) != -1)
        {
            Response.Write(nextRole + "<br/>");
        }
    }
```