# how to get combination of rows through query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with following fields and data.

```
id  type value
1   1    1
2   2    1
3   2    2
4   2    3
```

After running the query I should get result in temp table like below

```
1,1
1,2
1,3
```

and if i have multiple value in type 1 then it should do the same

so if the data is

```
 id  type value
 1   1    1
 2   1    2
 3   2    1
 4   2    2
 5   2    3
```

I should get result

```
1,1
1,2
1,3
2,1
2,2
2,3
```

Appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Unclear!!! what is logic behind output

Comment: Can you guess this sequence: 15, 16, 17, 23, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30  https://oeis.org/A090461

Comment: based on Type, I want to repeate the result set. So if I need all the combination of type 1 with type 2. (value of type 1 are (1,2) and values of type 2 are (1,2,3) i am looking to get 1,1 1,2 1,3  2,1 2,2 2,3).

Comment: BTW Amritpal and glenn fyi, this is called Cartesian Product. So glenn no need to guess 15, 16, 17, 23, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30...

Comment: Here are couple of links which explain it in detail 

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq.aspx

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710670/c-sharp-permutation-of-an-array-of-arraylists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like:

```
SELECT t1.value, t2.value
  FROM table t1
  JOIN table t2
    ON t1.type = 1
   AND t2.type = 2
;
```

which can also be written as:

```
SELECT t1.value, t2.value
  FROM ( SELECT value FROM table WHERE type = 1 ) t1
 CROSS
  JOIN ( SELECT value FROM table WHERE type = 2 ) t2
;
```

(The former is simpler, but the latter makes clearer that this is semantically a `CROSS JOIN`, since the join doesn't actually depend on any relationship between the joined records.)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ISNULL(CAST([type] as varchar(20)), '')
     + ','
     + ISNULL(CAST([value] as varchar(20)), '')
     AS CommaSeparated 
FROM types
```